# AngularJS: Should I use a single controller or two controllers on my airbnb-esque search page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question I**: Should I use two controllers, two services, or another structure for my airbnb-style search page?

**Question II**: I want to implement some search filters that will change data in multiple controllers/services/directives (from multiple inputs). Are there limits to the amount of two-way binding that can occur in an AngularJS app?

**Background**: I am learning AngularJS by making a web app that has functionality similar to airbnb. I want to accept a location from a user, then return Boat objects matching that location and plot them on a map. There will also be search filters (like price, max passengers...) that the user can edit. Here's a picture of the layout:
[image: layout]

*Boat object example*:

```
{
"id": 1,
"lat": "33.000",
"lng": "55.000",
"price": "...",
...
}
```

**Proposed Solution**: I initially conceived a plan like this:

[image: Module Structure]

**Concerns**: The two controllers will not share a scope, and I don't know how efficiently two-way data binding can address the issue. This led me to a solution similar to above, but using two services (MapController --> MapService) instead.

**Question Recap**: Should I use two services or two controllers for my app? Can two-way binding across 4+ controllers/services/directives address multiple inputs for search filters adequately?

Comment: According to single point of responsibility pattern each controller should handle a very specific task. short answer: use 2 controllers